# Access IDbSet using a string

Tags: c#, unit-of-work

To access a table in our Model I would use something like the following code:

`var item = _entities.Table.Where(x => x.Id = id).FirstOrDefault();`

_entities is our Model context and Table would be the name of a table in the Model.

How could I use a string to represent the name of the Table in the Model?
E.g.:

```
string tableName = "Table";
var item = _entities.tableName.Where(x => x.Id = id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You could use reflection to look for a property with that name, but you lose all compile-time type safety (you wouldn't be able to do `Where(x => x.Id = id)`) .  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are trying to update a table based on user input. The user will supply a spreadsheet and we will update the associated sql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a property by name, you do something along these lines:

```
object table = _entities.GetType().GetProperty("Table").GetValue(_entities, null);
```

This gets you the table as an `object`, which you can cast to an `IDbSet` or whichever other interface you have:

```
var table = _entities.GetType().GetProperty("Table").GetValue(_entities, null) as IDbSet;
```

Note that you won't have the advantage of type safety when doing it like this.  You can use the dynamic keyword, but then you're throwing type safety right out the window.

It might be preferable, if a bit fragile, to do something like:

```
if (tableName == "Table")
{
    _entities.Table...
}
else if (tableName == "OtherTable")
{
    _entities.OtherTable....
}
```

At least doing it this way, you have the compiler watching your back.